# How to set WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" in saml app in Okta

Tags: saml-2.0, okta

I am creating a SAML 2.0 app in OKTA developer account, after creation when I go look at IdentityProvider metadata I always see WantAuthnRequestsSigned="false"  how can I set it to WantAuthnRequestSigned to true?

Answer (score 2):

Okta doesn't support signed requests. Neither does Onelogin. I've never asked why, it seems the IDaaS platforms have consolidated on signed authentication requests being a waste of time.

Comment: why would they not accept signed requests? is it documented?

Comment: You'd need to ask them. They just don't. Old link to follow, but still applies. https://support.okta.com/help/s/question/0D50Z00008C3jZLSAZ/does-okta-validate-signature-on-saml-authentication-requests?language=en_US